# How to compare values with Json post xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, rest, dotnet-httpclient

I want to post the username and password using the JSON Post method so that I am able to login and get a token however I encounter some problems.

```
public async Task<string> GetActionResult(string url)
    {
        Uri geturi = new Uri("http://172.20.129.193/NYPStudentLifeService/" + url);
        var client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage responseGet = await client.PostAsync();
        responseGet.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string content = await responseGet.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return content;
    }
```

The sample body parameters Json

```
{
"AdminNo": "sample string 1",
"Password": "sample string 2"
}
```

Comment: Needs more information, like request headers, format, body etc...

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply! I've updated the question above hopefully it's enough

Comment: You create a uri called "geturi" but never actually use it. Your actual request has no URI at all, so of course it won't work. Set the left part of the uri (the fixed part) as the BaseURL of the http client object and put the right part (the url parameter) in the .PostAsync() call. Create a stringcontent object and insert the JSON body into it, then supply that to the .PostAsync() as well. Also, this question is not at all related to Xamarin.Forms it's related to consuming a REST web service, which is something I suggest you google how to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
using Newtonsoft.JSON;

//your login info
LoginInfo li = new LoginInfo(){AdminNo ="John Doe",Password="123456"};

// your response string
string response= await GetStreamAsync("url",li,null);

private async Task<string> GetStreamAsync(string url, object body, Dictionary<string, string> headers)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
     request.Accept = "application/json";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "POST";
    if (headers != null)
        foreach (var kv in headers)
            request.Headers[kv.Key] = kv.Value;
    var stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        if (body != null)
            writer.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body));
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Dispose();
    }

    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
    var respStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(respStream))
    {
        return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

public class LoginInfo
{
    public string AdminNo{get;set;}
    public string Password{get;set;}
}
```